# name 'X509Certificate2UI' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Does anyone had problem using X509Certificate2UI class in an Asp Net MVC4 application

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


private static X509Certificate2 PickCertificate(StoreLocation location, StoreName name)
{

    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        //PROBLEM IS HERE
        X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Caption", "Message", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)[0]; 
}
    catch (Exception)
    {               
        throw;
    }
}
```

It complains that there is no 'X509Certificate2UI' name in the current context
No idea since the class is in System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

Comment: The question [Visual Studio Code: Missing X509Certificate2UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947208/) may be helpfull

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to include reference for `System.Security.dll` into your project, since it
is not included in the `mscorlib` assembly, but in the `System.Security`
assembly.

Comment: Try now, I edited my first answer, didn't read question clearly. :(

Comment: That´s better. Found that earlier, just now I could test it and works fine. Reference: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/missing-x509certificate2ui-class-t2311992.html