# Visual Studio Code: Missing X509Certificate2UI

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, x509certificate2, system.security

I get the following error when trying to use an `X509Certificate2UI` in VS Code:

> The type or namespace name 'X509Certificate2UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.1]

I've found a [few sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617409/name-x509certificate2ui-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context/) that indicate the solution is to add the `system.security.dll` assembly, but these responses don't seem to be catered toward VS Code. I've already added the X509Certificates dependency to the project.json file, which doesn't seem to do me much good:

```json
"dependencies": {},
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {"type": "platform", "version": "1.1.0"},
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates": "4.3.0" //"4.3.0-*"
     },
     "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
```

Why am I getting this? What's wrong, and how can the issue be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X509Certificate2UI is not part of .NET Core.  It's a Windows-only class, and a UI class at that, and it was not carried over.

You will have to move to a UI-free solution, or cross-compile to target .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks bartonjs, this is very helpful. Is there a resource you know of that lists which classes aren't carried over to .NET Core, in case I run into this again and want to verify?

Comment: https://apisof.net/ is fairly useful.  It doesn't say when something's missing, so you have to know what you're looking for. https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI says .NET Framework 2.0+, but doesn't mention .NET Core (compare to https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error above appeared because i wanted to try out the console example from the page [X509Certificate2UI Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

I did the following in vs code terminal

```
dotnet new console --use-program-main
dotnet add package System.Windows.Extensions --version 7.0.0
dotnet add package System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates --version 4.3.2
```

This did the trick.

##### Console example for X509Certificate2UI Class

This is the shortened code from the page [X509Certificate2UI Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) it returns a warning for [PublicKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.publickey?view=net-7.0)

> warning SYSLIB0027: 'PublicKey.Key' is obsolete: 'PublicKey.Key is
> obsolete. Use the appropriate method to get the public key, such as
> GetRSAPublicKey.'

The `warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms.` can be avoided by adding the attribute `[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]` above the class (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72006246/819887)).

```cs
// may require using System.Runtime.Versioning;
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")] 
static void Main()
{
  X509Store store = new X509Store("MY",StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

  var collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
  var fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(
                        X509FindType.FindByTimeValid,
                        DateTime.Now,false);
  var scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                      fcollection, "Test Certificate Select",
                      "Select a cert from list to get information",
                      X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection);
  Console.WriteLine("Number of certificates: {0}{1}",
                       scollection.Count, Environment.NewLine);

  foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in scollection)
  {
     try {
        byte[] rawdata = x509.RawData;
        Console.WriteLine("Content Type: {0}{1}",
              X509Certificate2.GetCertContentType(rawdata),Environment.NewLine);
        // ....
     } catch (CryptographicException) {
        Console.WriteLine("Information could not be written out for this certificate.");
     }
   }
   store.Close();
  }
}
```