# CA1416. How to tell builder that only platform is Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-5

`dotnet run` (on windows) causes
`warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'WellKnownSidType.WorldSid' is only supported on: 'windows'.`

My program is designed to run only on windows.

I tried to add `SupportedPlatform` to `MyApp.csproj`, but no luck.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices" Version="5.0.0" />
    <SupportedPlatform Include="Windows"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I show `dotnet run` that this project is windows-only?

Comment: Change ***Target OS*** in properties for project (Console, REST API,...) ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can mark each windows-specific method with `System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatformAttribute` e.g.

```cs
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public static void Foo()
    => Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

Mark entire assembly with in AssemblyInfo (if you have one)

```cs
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatformAttribute("windows")]
```

Or edit `.csproj` file to target windows-specific version of dotnet to make these changes automatic

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: Does the SupportedOSPlatform revers to the machine on which the dotnet app is being run, or the os platforms that user can reach the app from?

Comment: @TK-421, you can read about it in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/platform-compat-analyzer)

Comment: I've read this whole article that you linked, but can't find an answer anywhere. I am making an ASP.NET website that will be hosted on a Windows IIS and uses a Windows-specific method. Does that mean that users using Linux can't access my website, or everything will be okay because the app runs on a windows?

Comment: @TK-421, this attribute is only a recommendation from compiler to developer. It won't affect users of website

Comment: Last one does nothing (testing with .NET 6).

Comment: @NickeManarin do you have `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` somewhere in project or `Directory.build.props`?

Comment: @JL0PD Yes, I have. Removing it fixed the issue. Of course, I just had to migrate the app details (version, names, etc) to the project.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71097598/how-to-globally-specify-android-and-ios-are-not-supported-in-a-net-5-0-app/71106689#71106689 for more specific details on how `<TargetFramework>..` is handled

Answer (score 10):

1. Removed the AssemblyInfo.cs file.
2. Removed the following from the .csproj file

   < GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</ GenerateAssemblyInfo>
3. Add to the .csproj file

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>

       <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>

       <PlatformName>windows</PlatformName>

       <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>"
   ```

   </ Project>

Comment: Great answer. Fixed everything for me. I used it in my .Net 7 app with <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>

Comment: funny thing: WinExe will discard all your logs if you're launching your exe as a child process AHAHA; thanks

Comment: The whole point of `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` is to get rid of that dreaded `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Certainly don't want to disable this new feature just because of this little glitch.