# How to globally specify android and ios are not supported in a .net 5.0 app

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using System.IO.Ports in a .net 5.0 project. This generates warnings as follows:

> warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'SerialPort.Close()' is unsupported on: 'ios', 'android'.

I can put guards in to check the platform before calling SerialPort methods, but I calls these in a lot of places.

Instead I was wondering if there was a way to tell .net at the project level that I don't support ios and android.

I **don't** want to suppress all **CA1416** warnings because I **do** support:

- Windows ***and...***
- Linux

...and want to be warned if I use something not available on those platforms.

Comment: More like a warning for .NET 6 projects, but for some unknown reason applied to .NET 6 projects as well, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks Note that only .NET 6 has TFM like `net6-ios` or `net6-android`. I think you can safely ignore this warning for .NET 5. However, .NET 5 reaches end of life pretty soon, so anyway you should upgrade to .NET 6.

Answer (score 4):

Paraphrasing from the [warning documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416#tfm-target-platforms);

You can specify multiple "target framework moniker" (TFM) in your projects `<TargetFramework>` or `<TargetFrameworks>` tags. If the TFM has a target platform, the .NET SDK injects a `SupportedOSPlatform` attribute with the targeted platform name in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, which is consumed by the analyzer.

The analyzer doesn't seem to care which frameworks you target, just the `SupportedOSPlatform` / `UnsupportedOSPlatform` attributes compiled into your assembly.

While you can't specify a set of target frameworks that would allow windows and linux, but nothing else. That doesn't stop you from defining multiple `SupportedOSPlatform` attributes in your AssemblyInfo.cs;

```cs
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

[assembly: SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
[assembly: SupportedOSPlatform("linux")]
```

Which I believe should limit how the CA1416 warnings are generated. Even if your project references `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`.

Answer (score 1):

---

**TL; DR:** essentially your question is divided into two parts and sadly only one appears to be possible.

---

### 1. How to exclude an OS from your project

OP:

> How to globally specify android and ios are not supported in a .net 5.0 app

> I can put guards in to check the platform before calling SerialPort methods, but I calls these in a lot of places.

Yes. Instead of allowing all destinations that say `net5.0` provides, you can fine-tune your output by using the plural `<TargetFrameworks>` element (note the "s") instead of the default `<TargetFramework>`<sup>1</sup>.

Here's an example project that targeting `net5.0`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The above project will let your app compile for all OSs including Windows, Mac OS, **Android and iOS**.

> Instead I was wondering if there was a way to tell .net at the project level that I don't support ios and android.

Yes.  To achieve that we would use OS-specific TFMs instead of the general `net5.0`. <sup>1</sup>

1. change `<TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>`
2. change `net5.0` to `net5.0-windows;net5.0-macos`

...like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows;net5.0-macos</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

With this iOS and Android support have been removed.

### 2. How to exclude Linux

OP:

> I don't want to suppress all CA1416 warnings because I do support Windows and Linux

This is where it gets tricky as Microsoft has not defined a TFM for Linux (too many flavours?) so the only way to specify that you want to target Linux is to use `net5.0`.  Linux support is implied.  Unfortunately this **re-activates** support for **iOS and Android** the very thing we just removed.  It also activated MacOS which you might not care about.

---

<sup>1</sup> *[Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework)*
, MSFT

Comment: "so the only way to specify that you want to target Linux is to use net5.0" which also adds android and ios support, which gets me right back where I started.

Comment: @trampster thanks but I hadn't finished. ;)

Comment: 2 years later, and apparently he still isn't finished :D