# Why I'm getting the exception: "System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.CheckStatus(int status)" when running the app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bitmap

I'm using a method named: `Image_resize` to resizing my images, but when I call this method, I get:

> ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
> System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.CheckStatus(int status)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing ArgumentException: Parameter is
> not valid. System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.CheckStatus(int
> status) System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(string filename, bool useIcm)
> System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(string filename)
> Keyhanatr.Core.ImageMethods.ImageConvertor.Image_resize(string
> input_Image_Path, string output_Image_Path, int new_Width) in
> ImgMehods.cs
> +
> Bitmap source_Bitmap = new Bitmap(input_Image_Path); Keyhanatr.Core.ImageMethods.ImgMehods.CreateProductImg(IFormFile
> imgUp) in ImgMehods.cs
> +
> ImageConvertor.Image_resize(imgPath,thumbPath,150); Keyhanatr.Core.Services.Products.ProductServices.AddProduct(Product
> product, IFormFile imgUp) in ProductServices.cs
> +
> product.ImageName = ImgMehods.CreateProductImg(imgUp); Keyhanatr.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProductsController.Create(Product
> product, IFormFile imgUp) in ProductsController.cs
> +
> _productServices.AddProduct(product, imgUp);

Also getting green squiggle under some lines.
The used method is as fallowing :

```cs
public static class ImageConvertor
{
    public static void Image_resize(string input_Image_Path, string output_Image_Path, int new_Width)
    {
        const long quality = 50L;
        Bitmap source_Bitmap = new Bitmap(input_Image_Path);
        double dblWidth_origial = source_Bitmap.Width;
        double dblHeigth_origial = source_Bitmap.Height;
        double relation_heigth_width = dblHeigth_origial / dblWidth_origial;
        int new_Height = (int)(new_Width * relation_heigth_width);

        //< create Empty Drawarea >
        var new_DrawArea = new Bitmap(new_Width, new_Height);
        //</ create Empty Drawarea >

        using (var graphic_of_DrawArea = Graphics.FromImage(new_DrawArea))
        {
            //< setup >
            graphic_of_DrawArea.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            graphic_of_DrawArea.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphic_of_DrawArea.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            //</ setup >

            //< draw into placeholder >
            //*imports the image into the drawarea
            graphic_of_DrawArea.DrawImage(source_Bitmap, 0, 0, new_Width, new_Height);
            //</ draw into placeholder >

            //--< Output as .Jpg >--
            using (var output = System.IO.File.Open(output_Image_Path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //< setup jpg >
                var qualityParamId = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
                var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityParamId, quality);
                //</ setup jpg >

                //< save Bitmap as Jpg >
                var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                new_DrawArea.Save(output, codec, encoderParameters);
                //resized_Bitmap.Dispose ();
                output.Close();
                //</ save Bitmap as Jpg >
            }
            //--</ Output as .Jpg >--
            graphic_of_DrawArea.Dispose();
        }
        source_Bitmap.Dispose();
        //---------------</ Image_resize() >---------------
    }
}
```

It's that I was using this method in other project before and it was working well, but I don't know why it doesn't work here at this project!
Anyone can help?

Comment: what operating system ?

Comment: @DanielA.White Windows

Comment: The exception is coming from `System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(string filename)`, it seems to be an invalid image file or with some format that .NET doesn't understand (maybe wrong extension?)

Comment: Enable displaying the warnings in the error output window to see what the green squiggles mean, or just hover with the mouse over them to display a tooltip.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  I just hoverd on `Bitmap` and it said: **This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Bitmap' is only supported on: 'Windpws'**

Comment: See: [How to fix C# Warning CA1416 in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66735113/880990).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Where or how do I must use it? Because I just tried the way in the given link above but it doesn't made any difference and I got the same exception again!

Comment: The squiggles have nothing to do with the exception. Have you checked the file that causing the exception? Can you open it with whatever image viewer?

Comment: @Steeeve There is no wrong with the uploaded file

Comment: @Steeeve When debugging, it stops on `double dblWidth_origial = source_Bitmap.Width;` and sayes: **user UnHandeled exception** :(

Comment: The exception you posted is another one. What are the details of the new one?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and found that you should check width and height `not zero` first.

`var new_DrawArea = new Bitmap(new_Width, new_Height)`